# How to get weights from tflite model?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a simple network and I have done pruning and quantization using tensorflow. I am specifically following this tutorial to apply on my network:
https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/pruning_with_keras#convert_to_tensorflow_lite

In the end, I get tflite file. I want to extract weights from this file. How I can get weights from this quantized model? I know the method about getting weights from 'h5' file but not from 'tflite' file. Or is there any other way to save 'h5' file after quantization has been performed on the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using Netron. In Netron, weights can be saved as numpy array.
https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron

Answer (score 8):

Create a tflite interpreter and (optionally) perform inference. tflite_interpreter.get_tensor_details() will give a list of dictionaries that have weights, biases, their scales, zero_points..etc.

```
'''
Create interpreter, allocate tensors
'''
tflite_interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path='model_file.tflite')
tflite_interpreter.allocate_tensors()

'''
Check input/output details
'''
input_details = tflite_interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = tflite_interpreter.get_output_details()

print("== Input details ==")
print("name:", input_details[0]['name'])
print("shape:", input_details[0]['shape'])
print("type:", input_details[0]['dtype'])
print("\n== Output details ==")
print("name:", output_details[0]['name'])
print("shape:", output_details[0]['shape'])
print("type:", output_details[0]['dtype'])

'''
Run prediction (optional), input_array has input's shape and dtype
'''
tflite_interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_array)
tflite_interpreter.invoke()
output_array = tflite_interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

'''
This gives a list of dictionaries. 
'''
tensor_details = tflite_interpreter.get_tensor_details()

for dict in tensor_details:
    i = dict['index']
    tensor_name = dict['name']
    scales = dict['quantization_parameters']['scales']
    zero_points = dict['quantization_parameters']['zero_points']
    tensor = tflite_interpreter.tensor(i)()

    print(i, type, name, scales.shape, zero_points.shape, tensor.shape)

    '''
    See note below
    '''
```

- Conv2D layers will have three dicts associated with them: kernel, bias, conv_output, each with its scales, zero_points, and tensors.
- tensor - is the np array with kernel weights or biases. For conv_output or activation, this doesn't mean anything (not the intermediate output)
- For conv kernel's dictionary, tensor is shaped (cout, k , k,cin)